# Setting a ColdFusion variable

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I have a problem setting a variable where I am unable to set a variable as a ColdFusion variable that calculates anything that is less than or equals to 90 days from today as shown below. I am getting an error when I try to set the variable as below:

```
sLate = now() >= 90
```

If I cannot create a variable as above, I would like to compare dates between now, and 90 days before now, and publish the output to a variable.

Comment: That is not the correct syntax for calculating dates with ColdFusion. Have you consulted the documentation? There are a number of date manipulation functions. Also, are you trying to compare dates in a record set? If so, you'd be better off retrieving the sub-set of dates using database specific date functions.

Comment: If cf 8 supports the ternary operator you can use that.  Otherwise you can use if/else logic.  Oh, yeah, read @iKnowKungFoo's comment.

Comment: @DanBracuk unfortunately CF8 doesn't support ternary

Comment: We need more context. What is the exact error message and the *actual code* that produces it. The above is not valid syntax for cfscript or cfml. Also, what is your ultimate goal here?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
<cfset sLate=DateAdd("d",-90,now())>
```

If in cfscript:
    sLate=DateAdd("d",-90,now());

As others have mentioned you are using wrong syntax. Also from your last line I understand that you want a value 90 days earlier than now. -90 will give a value 90 days earlier and using 90 will provide value of 90 days later from current day.

Comment: Downvoted for two reasons.  One, it doesnt' really answer the question.  Two, the result of the code you posted will include a time component, something that is generally undesirable when looking at "90 days from today".

Comment: @Dan how do you decide that time component is undesirable? Coding is not done on perceptions but on substance/data. User wants to calculate/set a variable which is less than 90 days from now. Doesn't my answer answers that?

Comment: Since you asked, the question said, "90 days from today".  It did not say, "90 days from now".  In any event, the important person, the person who asked the question, thinks that your answer does pertain to the question.

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet should give you a little heads up on how to work with dates. Note that you may want to strip the time portion out of the dates as you might get unexpected results.

e.g. Without striping the time element comparing these values will give you ZERO
instead of 1 as expected.

```
<cfset dateA = createDateTime(2014,6,4,0,13,0,0)>
<cfset dateB = createDateTime(2014,6,5,0,1,0,0)>
Result A:#dateDiff("d",dateA,dateB)#<br>

<cfset dateA = createDate(2014,6,4)>
<cfset dateB = createDate(2014,6,5)>
Result B:#dateDiff("d",dateA,dateB)#<br>
```

Hope this example points you in the right direction.

```
<cfset TODAY = now()>
<cfset pastDate = dateAdd("d",-90,TODAY)>
<cfset myDate = createDate(2014,6,4)>
<cfset pastDays = dateDiff("d",myDate,TODAY)>

<cfoutput>
Today:#TODAY#<br>
90 days before today:#pastDate#<br>
My Date:#myDate#<br>
My Date happened #pastDays# days before today.
</cfoutput>
```